# How to find points that lie on a line equidistant from each other

Tags: swift, geometry, swift2

Using Swift, from the diagram below given two points A and C, how can I find points B1, B2 and B3 knowing that they are equidistant (of equal distance) from each other.

[image]

Comment: What doesn't work with your current implementation? Show us the code.

Comment: You're given two points, so you can calculate the slope and the distance. If you can do that, you can also calculate the positions with distances `1/(n+1)` where `n` is the number of intermediate points. Just write down the equation of the line in point-slope form and take it from there.

Comment: @Caleb, thanks for the explanation, I guess I was on the right track. Do you mind taking a look at my previous question for me http://goo.gl/iqSmQq

Comment: @EricD. Well noted, I should have added code, I guess that's why I got the down votes. I hope you don't mind taking a look at my previous question for me http://goo.gl/iqSmQq

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is working code.

```
func findEquidistantPoints(startPoint: CGPoint, endPoint: CGPoint, pointsCount: UInt) -> [CGPoint] {

    let count = CGFloat(pointsCount + 1)
    let xDelta = (endPoint.x - startPoint.x) / count
    let yDelta = (endPoint.y - startPoint.y) / count

    return Array(1...pointsCount).map { CGPoint(x: startPoint.x + CGFloat($0) * xDelta, y: startPoint.y + CGFloat($0) * yDelta) }
}

findEquidistantPoints(CGPoint(x: 10, y: 23), endPoint: CGPoint(x: 34, y: 45), pointsCount: 3)
```